# AWS Batch Container Error: "no users found"

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-batch

When triggering a batch job (Fargate Job Queue), the status is going to FAILED with the following error message:

> Cannotstartcontainererror: ResourceInitializationError: unable to
> create new container: mount callback failed on
> /tmp/containerd-mount3975084381: no users found

Unfortunately I can't find any similar errors online.

For reference, the Dockerfile that I'm building is simply the following:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
WORKDIR /app
USER root

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python3", "run.py"]
```

And the contents of run.py are as folows:

```
print("Python script has run!")
```

The only other file in the image is `requirements.txt`, which contains just the line `requests`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed my own issue:

The job definition had the user set to `ubuntu`, which wasn't available in the `python:3.8-slim-buster` image.

Changing this to `root` fixed the issue.